# Run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: ssis

To run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio you must install __ of Integration Services or higher.

anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: You should have `Integration Service Instance` installed to exeute SSIS package outside BIDS using `SQL Agent or C# or VB application` or also using `DTEXEC`  utility

Comment: what version of Business Intelligence Development Studio are you using to develop the SSIS package and what version are you trying to deply too?